# Implementing Upvote using Pjax

Tags: yii2

I want to submit data without reloading the page. So I used Pjax. When I click on upvote(views\site\vote.php:), the page reloads and returns an error saying `undefined variable: id`. I wish to know why and how to solve this problem.I think it is due to `id=>$id`.

*views\site\vote.php:*

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
    <?= Html::a('upvote', ['site/upvote', 'id'=>$id]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

But with `'id'=>18` instead of `'id'=>$id`, it works (submits, page doesn't reload and does not return an error).

```
    <?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]); ?>
    <?= Html::a('upvote', ['site/upvote', 'id'=>18]) ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

*controllers\SiteController.php:*

```
public function actionVote()
{  
   $id=18;
   return $this->render('vote',[
       /* 5 other variables */
       'id'=>$id,
   ]);
}

public function actionUpvote($id)
{
    .....
    return $this->render('vote');
}
```

Comment: Your action `actionUpvote()` does not send the variable `$id` via the render function, as it does in `actionVote()`.

Comment: The content of the action `actionVote` is too large. So recopying it in the action `actionUpvote` will lead to redundancy .I studied it from http://blog.neattutorials.com/examples/pjax/web/site/vote. The only difference is that, I used a variable `$id` in the `html a tag` while they used an integer. @Jørgen